# How to work around the mobile/phone keyboard in a website that resizes automatically based on window width/height

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, resize

I make web-apps that often resize themselves according to the window via (lately) CSS transforms.

For desktop PCs, it's not a big deal.. I just run my resize test code every 50ms, checking the window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight. (I don't use the 'resize' event here because when a user resizes the window, the event is run potentially too quickly/too many times..)

On phones, I use both a "resize" and "orientationchange" event. Resize events are sometimes need because of various Android (Chrome/webview)/iOS bugs. Works well.

**The problem**: as we all know, currently there is no way to explicitly detect a few different phone-only events, like the virtual keyboard popping in and out. Thus, when a keyboard pops up, this triggers the resize event, which triggers my resize routine and causes the app window to get really really small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Thus, when a keyboard pops up, this triggers the resize event, which triggers my resize routine and causes the app window to get really really small."

One way to fix this is to detect for blur and focus on text/password inputs.

**Sub-problem**: we also need to guard against the possibility that the user will re-orient their device while the keyboard is visible -- thus sending incorrect data to the resize routine. This can be handled by blurring the input when an orientationchange event occurs.

Example code:

```
if (gs.is_phone_or_tablet) {
 window.keyboard_is_visible = false
 $(document.body).on('focus', 'input[type="text"], input[type="password"]', function () {window.keyboard_is_visible = true})
 $(document.body).on('blur' , 'input[type="text"], input[type="password"]', function () {window.keyboard_is_visible = false})
 var hide_keyboard = function () {
  if (document.activeElement == document.body) return
  document.activeElement.blur ()
  window.keyboard_is_visible = false
 }
 //window.addEventListener('resize'           , hide_keyboard) // <-- for Webview <= 4.3 only..
 window.addEventListener('orientationchange', hide_keyboard)
}
```